# Flutter contains TROJ_GEN?

Tags: flutter, antivirus

**Hello everybody**

I built an application and when I checked it on Virustotal website there is TROJ_GEN.
Then I built an empty Flutter application and tested it, showing the same result
What is the solution ?

```
  flutter version 3.13.7
  dropdown_button2: ^2.3.9
  firebase_core: ^2.17.0
  flutter_native_splash: ^2.3.3
  flutter_screenutil: ^5.8.4
  get: ^4.6.6
  hive: ^2.2.3
  http: ^1.1.0
  image_picker: ^1.0.4
  intl: ^0.18.1
  pin_code_fields: ^8.0.1
  qr_flutter: ^4.1.0 
  scan: ^1.6.0
  package_info_plus: ^4.1.0
  path_provider: ^2.1.1
  awesome_notifications: ^0.8.2
  firebase_messaging: ^14.6.9
```

***I built by use codemagic.io and same results.***

[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxQbn.png)

Comment: It's a false positive. Report it to Virustotal with a way for them to reproduce/test it.

Comment: Here are two links to such reports https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/90e023678338929f2109219d26b2c523974253bb9f9348625f3b5060dd349907 and https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/0c2be6e912086ce031b7f72fdedb562e35015d24dfa9648fce81113f4a57550c , Interesting: the reported trojan is not the same code. The app is not mine, but it holds me back from installing

Answer (score 1):

I built an empty Flutter application on version 3.10.0 its clean,
and  I built an empty Flutter application on version 3.16.0 - channel beta its clean.